# Show data based on page size selected in "Show Dropdown" in Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to show records based on selected page size in dropdown in jquery datatable.

But it hits the api only once and selects 10 records only.. and when I change page size.. it does not hits the api..

Below is my DataTable Code

```
var dataTable = _ApiMappingTable.DataTable({
            processing: true,
            listAction: {
                ajaxFunction: _serviceApiPath.getAll,
            },
            initComplete: function (settings, json) {
                abp.ui.clearBusy($divApiMapping);
            },
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: 0, data: "requestType" },
                { targets: 1, data: "apiPath" },
                {
                    targets: 2,
                    defaultContent: '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary blue btnWebHook">Map WebHook</button>'
                },
            ]
        });
```

Please take a look on this screenshot.
http://prntscr.com/jeq3hc

Any help please?

Comment: is `serverSide: true` ??

Comment: @SreenathPG - I made it true and pagination is working fine.Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Doing this, My Paging is working fine

```
 paging: true,
 serverSide: true,
```